# Nginx Unique ID for the request and asset request

Tags: http, nginx, lua

I am using Nginx as a reverse proxy and would like to know if it is possible to log an entire HTTP transaction by ID in the access log.

For example if I go to a website and there are 50 assets, such as css, js and images the server will make 51 separate HTTP request. I would like to know how to identify the the assets were loaded as a part of the initial web page request and did not visit the asset directly.

Thanks for any help or direction.

Comment: What sort of ID do you want to use? HTTP requests have no inherent ID; you'd have to invent one.

Comment: The simplest thing is looking at HTTP referer field.